# Upload Image, Save to Database, Create Thumbnail and Display in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an Image Gallery mostly for learning ASP.Net MVC. After many hours of googling and stackoverflowing, I have finally accomplished the goal of uploading image, saving to database, creating a thumbnail and showing in View. My code shown below is bloated to say the least and I am looking for any kind suggestion on how to improve it.

Here is the View form input

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageData, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
<input name="Image" type="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageData)
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Create Action in the Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(ArtWork artwork, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    //attach the uploaded image to the object before saving to Database
                    artwork.ImageMimeType = image.ContentLength;
                    artwork.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(artwork.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);

                    //Save image to file
                    var filename = image.FileName;
                    var filePathOriginal = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Originals");
                    var filePathThumbnail = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails");
                    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathOriginal, filename);
                    image.SaveAs(savedFileName);

                    //Read image back from file and create thumbnail from it
                    var imageFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Originals"), filename);
                    using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
                    using (var newImage = new Bitmap(100, 100))
                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        var thumbNew = File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
                        artwork.ArtworkThumbnail = thumbNew.FileContents;
                    }                
                }

               //Save model object to database
                db.ArtWorks.Add(artwork);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(artwork);
        }
```

And here is a Action method to get the Thumbnail from Database

```
public FileContentResult GetThumbnailImage(int artworkId)
        {
            ArtWork art = db.ArtWorks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ArtWorkId == artworkId);
            if (art != null)
            {
                return File(art.ArtworkThumbnail, art.ImageMimeType.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And finally to display in the view here,

```
<td>
            <img src="@Url.Action("GetThumbnailImage", "Artwork", new { Model.ArtWorkId })" alt="Artwork Image" />
        </td>
```

Like I said, this works, but I am sure there will be better ways to upload, save and retrieve images from the database using ASP.Net and Entity Framework.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review.  This question is more suited on [CodeReview.StackExchange.Com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)